# Polycom 550 not connecting to network...is this phone the issue?

Tags: networking, voip

I have an end user who is using a Polycom 550 phone which connects via their home network to our PBX. I have gone through the following troubleshooting steps:

With the phone plugged into the user's router, the router doesn't light up recognizing that the phone has been plugged in.

I had the user change Cat5e cables to one he knew worked and this didn't make a difference.

The user plugged in a different device to the Cat5e cable that was being used for the phone and at that point the router lights did light up for that port.

The phone obviously isn't connecting to our PBX even though his internet connection is working fine.

I haven't had any of these phones die on me before but it seems like that must be the case here...do you guys agree? Just looking for some verification before I go through the hassle of submitting an RMA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the user using the power supply and network cables that came with the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your next step is to get another phone and try that. You seem to have verified the cable is good. Either that or take this phone to another location that you know has a working phone setup and plug it in to see if it works there. If it's still dead, it's the phone.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what I was thinking...was just looking for some verification. Thanks!